# To prove identity $P(n,3)= \lfloor n^2/12 \rfloor$

Tags: integers, integer-partitions

Suppose $P(n,k)$ is number of partitions of positive integer n by k positive integers with no duplicative tuples. And
$\lfloor r\rfloor$ is largest of integers equal or less than real number $r$

If $n\not\equiv 3\pmod6$
Then $P(n,3)=\lfloor \frac{n^2}{12}\rfloor$.

My bruteforcing answer is that 
$P(n,3)$
$=(\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor} num.(a,b):a\leq b, a+b+i=n)$
$=(\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor} \lfloor\frac{n-i}{2}\rfloor-i+1)$
And it is seen that the identity holds for each cases where $n\equiv 0,1,2,4,5\pmod6$
thus statement is true.

However i think there should be more general and less repetitive approach for this which i can't do.

Ideas?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, $P(4,3)=0$ which is not $\lfloor\frac{4^2}{12}\rfloor$.

Comment: You did misunerstand the question sir.

Comment: So how do you write $4$ as a partition of $3$ positive integers?

Comment: @David $$4=2+1+1$$

Comment: @David It's a partition of $4$ **into** $3$ positive integers, i.e., $4$ written as a **sum** of $3$ positive integers.

Comment: There i find my misleading definition. You should count distinct tuples not tuples of disinct positive integers. My appologies for wasting your time. I edited the wrong wording.

Comment: @Solvable Potato I suggest you use the wording "no duplicated tuples" instead of "no duplicates" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @bof The original wording appeared to specify no repeated integers, so $2+1+1$ would not have been counted.  It's been changed now.

Comment: @David English does not seem to be the OP's first language. I didn't pay much attention to the wording, I went by the statement "If $n\not\equiv 3\pmod6$ Then $P(n,3)=\lfloor \frac{n^2}{12}\rfloor$" which is correct for the number of partitions into $3$ parts with no further restrictions, but would be wrong for partitions into $3$ unequal parts. Also, your comment that I replied to asked "how do you write $4$ as a partition of $3$ positive integers, not "$3$ distinct positive integers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(n,k)$ is the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. (It is also the number of partitions of $n$ into any number of parts with greatest part equal to $k$; also, for $n\ge k$, the number of partitions of $n-k$ into parts of size at most $k$.)

$P(n,3)$ is OEIS sequence [A069905](http://oeis.org/A069905).

You are probably familiar with the identity
$$P(n,k)=P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-k,k)\quad\quad(n\ge k\ge1);\tag1$$
if not, observe that $P(n-1,k-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts with least part **equal to** $1$, and $P(n-k,k)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts with least part **greater than** $1$. We need this for $k=3$:
$$P(n,3)=P(n-1,2)+P(n-3,3)\quad\quad(n\ge3)\tag2.$$
Since $P(n,2)=\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$, we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$P(n,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor+P(n-3,3)\quad\quad(n\ge3).\tag3$$
Applying $(3)$ twice, we get
$$P(n,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n-4}2\right\rfloor+P(n-6,3)\quad\quad(n\ge6).\tag4$$
Since
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n-4}2\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}\frac{n-2}2+\frac{n-4}2=n-3\quad\text{ if }n\text{ is even },\\
\frac{n-1}2+\frac{n-5}2=n-3\quad\text{ if }n\text{ is odd },
\end{cases}$$
we can rewrite $(4)$ as
$$P(n,3)=P(n-6,3)+n-3\quad\quad(n\ge6).\tag5$$
Hence, if we suppose that $n\ge6$ and
$$P(n-6,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{(n-6)^2}{12}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2-12n+36}{12}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{12}\right\rfloor-n+3,$$
it follows by $(5)$ that
$$P(n,3)=P(n-6,3)+n-3=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{12}\right\rfloor.$$
Since the equality $P(n,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{12}\right\rfloor$ holds for the base cases $n=0,1,2,4,5$, it follows by induction that it holds whenever $n\not\equiv3\pmod6$.

**Remark.** In the same way, we can show that the identity
$$P(n,3)=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2+3}{12}\right\rfloor$$
holds for all $n$ without exception.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler method with three cases:

All three same:  $x=1$ for $0 \pmod 6$ and $x=0$ for $1,2,4,5 \pmod 6$

Two same: $y=\lfloor {n-1\over 2} \rfloor$

All different: $z={{n-1 \choose 2} - x - 3y \over  6} = {n^2-3n+2-2x\over 12} - \lfloor {n-1\over 4} \rfloor$

Now count the total: $x+y+z = {n^2-3n+2+10x\over 12} + \lfloor {n-1\over 4} \rfloor= {n^2-3n+2+10x\over 12} + \lfloor {3n-3\over 12} \rfloor = \lfloor {n^2+10x-1\over 12} \rfloor$

For $0 \pmod 6$: $\lfloor {n^2+10x-1\over 12} \rfloor = \lfloor {n^2+9\over 12} \rfloor$, However since $12\mid n^2$ and $9<12$, this is same as $\lfloor {n^2\over 12} \rfloor$

For $1,2,4,5\pmod 6$ : $\lfloor {n^2+10x-1\over 12} \rfloor =\lfloor {n^2-1\over 12} \rfloor $. Since $12 \nmid n^2$ this is also equal to $\lfloor {n^2\over 12} \rfloor$.